# Can Programmers be used to list features of a certain kind of program?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I'm currently designing a (vector drawing) software. What choices do I have to get the list of most popular features such a software should have, in particular, features that if absent, would totally prevent users from using it ? How can this be asked in least ambiguous way ?

Comment: I don't really see that fitting at all, unless, maybe, if your piece of software is targeted at a very specific group of people/use-case.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see how you can ask such a question and have it be both on-topic and constructive.

As you propose it, it's a list. By definition, list questions are not constructive questions. However, even if you managed to remove the list component, it would still be off-topic. I don't see how it would fall into any of the topics that are listed in the FAQ as being on-topic.

If you have more widely-applicable questions about requirements, architecture, or design, those are on-topic. Some good starting places might be the tags for [requirements](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/requirements) or [requirements-management](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/requirements-management), [architecture](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture), or [design](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design). However, we can't give you those things or do your project for you.

Answer (score 1):

As Thomas [already mentioned](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5169/25936), this wouldn't really work as a question.

However it might work as a blog post, and if you feel you can write an interesting article about your project, explaining your design process and the features you are already planning to build, we'd love to host it in our [Community Blog](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com).

You will get feedback from the Programmers community through comments in your article, and of course it would be perfectly ok if you specifically asked for feedback on what features people would consider essential for your project.

If that's something you feel is worth pursuing, you should ping `@WorldEngineer` or `@Dynamic` in our [Blog chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2359/programmers-blog) for more details.

Comment: OK I'll consider doing this. I'm still gathering posible features in books, standards, and existing software,